# Select Statement UNION ALL with ALIAS is not outputting what is expected

Tags: query, dataextensions, marketing-cloud

```
SELECT c.SubscriberKey,
       c.EventDate AS EventDate_Click,
       c.JobID,
       c.URL AS URL_Click,
       NULL AS EventDate_Open,
       NULL AS EventDate_Sent,
       j.EmailId AS EmailId
FROM _Click c
UNION ALL
INNER JOIN _Job j ON c.JobId = j.JobId
SELECT s.SubscriberKey,
       s.EventDate AS EventDate_Sent,
       s.JobID,
       NULL AS URL_Click,
       NULL AS EventDate_Open,
       NULL AS EventDate_Click,
       j.EmailId AS EmailId
FROM _Sent s
INNER JOIN _Job j ON s.JobId = j.JobId
UNION ALL
SELECT o.SubscriberKey,
       o.EventDate AS EventDate_Open,
       o.JobID,
       NULL AS URL_Click,
       NULL AS EventDate_Click,
       NULL AS EventDate_Sent,
       j.EmailId AS EmailId
FROM _OPEN o
INNER JOIN _Job j ON o.JobId = j.JobId
```

Is not giving expected results.

We should be recieving the eventDate in different columns for each union set but they all end up in the same column. The column that is first aliased in the first select statement.

We are on an s7 instance running with over 30 million rows. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: this is off topic. its is not sales force question.